# pytest --cov is telling me I haven't imported something that I have

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage

Here's what I run, and what I get:

```
me $ pytest --cov MakeInfo.py
================================================================================ test session starts =================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /Users/me/Documents/workspace-vsc/Pipeline/src/python
plugins: cov-2.12.1, arraydiff-0.3, remotedata-0.3.2, doctestplus-0.4.0, openfiles-0.4.0
collected 42 items                                                                                                                                                                   

test_MakeInfo.py ............                                                                                                                                                  [ 28%]
test_MakeJSON.py ...                                                                                                                                                           [ 35%]
test_convert_refflat_to_bed.py ..                                                                                                                                              [ 40%]
test_generate_igv_samples.py ...                                                                                                                                               [ 47%]
test_sample_info_to_jsons.py ....                                                                                                                                              [ 57%]
read_coverage/test_intervaltree.py .........                                                                                                                                   [ 78%]
util/test_util.py .........                                                                                                                                                    [100%]**Coverage.py warning: Module MakeInfo.py was never imported**. (module-not-imported)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
WARNING: Failed to generate report: No data to report.

/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_cov/plugin.py:271: PytestWarning: Failed to generate report: No data to report.

  self.cov_controller.finish()
```

Here's the top of test_MakeInfo.py:

```
import pytest
import os
import sys
import json

import MakeInfo
from MakeInfo import main, _getNormalTumorInfo
```

What I'm looking for: Tell me how much of MakeInfo.py is covered by tests in test_MakeInfo.py

What I'm getting: confused

Is my command wrong for what I want?  Nothing calls into MakeInfo.py, it's stand alone and called from the command line.  So of course none of the other tests are including it.

Is there a way to tell pytest --cov to look at this test file, and the source file, and ignore everything else?

Comment: Is there more content in `test_MakeInfo.py` than what you posted? Yes, you can tell pytest where to look at, see [the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/customize.html#configuration-file-formats).

Comment: Unfortunately, the pytest documentation doesn't tell me anything about using the coverage plugin for pytest.  At least, not that I could find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out that in this case the order of arguments is key

```
pytest test_MakeInfo.py --cov
```

Runs pytest on my one test file, and gives me coverage information for the one source file

```
pytest --cov test_MakeInfo.py
```

Tries to run against every test file (one of which was written by someone else on my team, and apparently uses a different test tool, so it throws up errors when pytest tries to run it)

```
pytest --cov MakeInfo
```

Is part way there: it runs all the tests, including the ones that fail, but then gives me the coverage information I want

So @Niel's answer is what you want if you have multiple test files targeting a single source file

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the call to just the python module name `MakeInfo` instead of the file name `MakeInfo.py`. Or if it is in an inner subdirectory, use the dot `.` notation e.g. `some_dir.some_subdir.MakeInfo`

```
pytest --cov MakeInfo
```

Comment: That gets a lot closer, since after running all the tests it actually gives me the coverage information for my file.  But see my answer for my final solution

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another reason that this message may appear.

The report was working fine on my local Windows machine. However, when it was run via our CI pipeline (Bitbucket Pipelines) the command was failing. The command I was using was

`python -m pytest --cov=pyMymodule --cov-fail-under=95 --junitxml=test-reports/report.xml tests`

Eventually, I realised I had made a typo for the module name, `pyMymodule` instead of `pyMyModule`. Windows/NTFS isn't case-sensitive, however, my pipeline was running Alpine Linux which was. Using the correct case for the module name sorted the issue for me.